# How do I prepare data (images) for py-faster-rcnn classification training?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning

I am trying to train my own image classificator with `py-faster-rcnn` [link](https://github.com/deboc/py-faster-rcnn) using my own images.

It looks rather simple in the [example here](https://github.com/deboc/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/help/Readme.md), but they are using some ready dataset (INRIA Person). Datasets are structured and cropped to sub-images (actually data sets there are both original images and cropped people images from them) and text notation of each image with coordinates of crops. Pretty straightforward.

Still I have no idea how this is done - do they use any sort of tool for this (I can hardly imagine some test lots of data are cropped and notated manually)?

Could anyone please suggest a solution for this one? Thanks.